# underlying provider failed on open - unique case with odbc/net connector

Tags: c#, .net, odbc

my connection string that has been working for months and completely unchanged started to not work today. when it connects to DB using this string now, it always appends the CURRENT SERVER IP to the username instead of going off what i specified as the server... (db and app server are different; db server is mysql not mssql, this has been working fine forever)

```
<add name="Model1Container" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=xx.xx.xxx.xxx;User Id=flow_xxxxxxxxxx;password=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;database=flow_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

this ends up in it trying to connect with userid@APPSERVERIP instead of userid@server_specified_in_conn_string and thus connection wont open.

makes no sense to me and makes even less sense that it didn't happen before....

connecting with connection string from within VS -- notice the disparity between server and the generated appendage to the userid specified...
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this particular user still has access to the database? Try using the same user to login to MySQL database from the command line.

Comment: do you not see that the user its trying to connect with is @ the wrong IP? of course i did check that, but if you read you can see this is irrelevant to the problem. its just connecting with @ 99-126... instead of @ 50-87...please look at the picture, at the two IP's...on the left is the db server ip, on the right is what its trying to authenticate with...what's confusing is that when i click OK on the left it tries to auth with a different IP...makes no sense!!

Comment: So the IP on the right, do you know which machine that is? Is it your local machine's IP?

Comment: as stated, the IP on the right is the webserver IP (in this case i was running locally, but when running on my server, its the webserver IP). the ip on the left is the DB IP. until today the same connection string and settings was authenticating with the IP on the left. if i explicitly specify the ip on the left it auth's with user@IP@IP